# how to parse specific values from multiple JSON objects into csv using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have following json

```
[
   {
      "ip":"105.105.105.105",
      "timestamp":"1543746097",
      "ports":[
         {
            "port":80,
            "proto":"tcp",
            "status":"open",
            "reason":"syn-ack",
            "ttl":128
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "ip":"105.105.105.105",
      "timestamp":"1543746097",
      "ports":[
         {
            "port":53,
            "proto":"tcp",
            "status":"open",
            "reason":"syn-ack",
            "ttl":128
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to extract ports to simple `csv` output

```
80,53
```

I tried

```
jq -r '.[]."ports" | map(.port) | @csv' 105.105.105.105_tcp.json
```

and

```
jq -r '.[]."ports" | map(.port) | join(",")' 105.105.105.105_tcp.json
```

but none of them work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a jq-only solution:

```
jq -r '[ .[].ports[].port ]|@csv' network.json
80,53
```

The approach here is to retrieve the port numbers, wrap them into an array, and then convert it to the CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get desired output by

```
jq -r '.[]."ports" | .[].port' 105.105.105.105_tcp.json | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,*$//g'
```

However I'm wondering if it can be done in more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

```
bash $ jtc -w'<port>l+0' -jr input.json | sed s/[][]//g 
 80, 53 
bash $
```

*[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)* will extract and print all ports and wrap those into the array. `sed` is needed to drop the arrays encasing